# How to acces Promethues datasource of Openshift Monitoring project from local Grafana server

Tags: openshift, prometheus, grafana

I want to use local Grafana server to monitor pods on Openshift4 platform. But I find the Grafana is unable to add built-in Prometheus of openshift-monitoring project as data source.
What should I do to fix this problem? or is there any other way to access monitoring data of openshift pod by my local server.

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation notes](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.6/monitoring/accessing-third-party-uis.html#accessing-third-party-uis-using-the-cli_accessing-third-party-uis):

> You can obtain URLs for the Prometheus, Alertmanager, and Grafana web UIs by using the OpenShift CLI (oc) tool.

So you should be able to retrieve the URL for Prometheus and query Prometheus from outside the cluster.

Comment: I'm getting `Error reading Prometheus: client_error: client error: 403` while testing the data source. @simon do you have any suggestions ?